# UnloadableImportException: Could not load imported ontology

Tags: java, rdf, owl, protege, owl-api

I have an ontology created in Protege 4.3.0 and stored in an OWL file. In order to load this ontology using the [OWL API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/), I use the following code sample.

```
public class MySampleClass {
    private final OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    private final OWLDataFactory df = manager.getOWLDataFactory();

    private final OWLReasonerFactory rf = new StructuralReasonerFactory();

    private final OWLOntology ontology;
    private final OWLOntologyID id;
    private final IRI iri;
    private final PrefixManager pm;

    private final OWLReasoner reasoner;

    /**
     * 
     * @param file
     */
    public MySampleClass(File file) {
        try {
            ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
        } catch (OWLOntologyInputSourceException | OWLOntologyCreationException ex) {
            // throw custom exception
        }

        id = ontology.getOntologyID();
        iri = id.getOntologyIRI();

        pm = new DefaultPrefixManager(iri.toString().concat("#"));

        reasoner = rf.createReasoner(ontology);
        reasoner.precomputeInferences(InferenceType.OBJECT_PROPERTY_ASSERTIONS);
    }
}
```

However, if I try to load an ontology that includes one or more imports, if these imports are not available, an UnloadableImportException is thrown, as the following example:

> org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.UnloadableImportException: Could not load
>   imported ontology: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core Cause:
>   connection timed out

How to solve this problem?
If the imported ontology is available offline, how to import this ontology during the loading of my ontology?

Comment: Note that the structural reasoner is not a complete reasoner. If you need proper reasoning, use a reasoner like HermiT or Pellet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `AutoIRIMapper` to point to a local folder containing local copies of ontologies.

```
AutoIRIMapper mapper=new AutoIRIMapper(folder, true);
manager.addIRIMapper(mapper);
```

Do this before starting to load ontologies.

Comment: For the owlapi v5 library, use this: 
manager.getIRIMappers().add(mapper);